# Java: Cannot Cast Object to Date in Comparator

Tags: java, date, object, casting

I am attempting to sort a collection of Dates in LinkedList myQueue by emptying it into  ArrayList myArrayList, sorting it via Comparator, then iterating over the linked list to place each Date back into the myQueue.

Everything works fine until I send the Date Objects into My Comparator for some reasin Casting the dates I created into Dates in the Comparator does not work.

Here is the Format the Dates are in:

```
    Thu Jul 30 00:00:00 JST 1908
```

Here is the Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to Date
at DateComparator.compare(DateComparator.java:14)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at QueueTest.main(QueueTest.java:76)
```

This is Where I place all Objects in myQueue into myArrayList:

```
    if (!myQueue.isEmpty()) {

            //Collections.sort(myQueue, new DateComparator());

            Object nextDate;

            ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

            while(!myQueue.isEmpty()){

                nextDate =  myQueue.removeFirst();

                myArrayList.add(nextDate);

            }

            Collections.sort(myArrayList, new DateComparator());

            Iterator it=myArrayList.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){

                myQueue.addLast(it.next());

            }
```

And this is where the issue is in My Comparator:

```
    Date d1 = (Date) a;
    Date d2 = (Date) b;
```

I just started going to school for Computer Science in Okinawa, got nobody to really talk to about this asides from my dog so any help is appreciated.

//EDIT:

This is the Date() SuperClass that My professor requires we use in order to create out Date Objects:

```
public class Date {

    private static int numberDates=0;    

    public static final int VALID_START_YEAR=1584; 

    private int year;  
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public Date() {
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 1970;
    numberDates++;   
    }

    public Date(int newMonth, int newDay, int newYear) {
    month = newMonth;
    day = newDay;
    year = newYear;
    numberDates++;   
    }


    public Date( Date other) {
    month = other.month;
    day = other.day;
    year = other.year;
    numberDates++;  
    }


    public Date( String date) {
    java.util.StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer(date,"/");

    month = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); //extract next token
    day =   Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    year =  Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    numberDates++;  
    }


    public int getYear() {
    return year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
    return month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
    return day;
    }


    public String toString() {
    return(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    }


    public static int getNumberDates() {
    return numberDates;
    }


    public void increment() {
    day++;   //stub for the actual method to be written later...
    }

    public static void clearNumberDates() {
    numberDates = 0;
    }



    public static boolean isValidDay(int month, int day, int year) {

    return true; 
    }


    public boolean equals( Object other ) { 

    if ((other instanceof Date) && 
        ((((Date)other).year==year) &&
         (((Date)other).month==month) &&
         (((Date)other).day==day)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;   
    }


    public int hashCode() {

    return (year + month + day) % 101;  
    }



    public int compareTo( Date other ) {
    if (equals(other))   
        return 0;

    else if (year < other.year)
        return -1;
    else if (year > other.year)
        return 1;

    else if (month < other.month)
        return -1;
    else if (month > other.month)
        return 1;

    else if (day < other.day)
        return -1;
    else if (day > other.day)
        return 1;
    else      
        return 0;    
    }
```

Comment: `java.sql.Date != java.util.Date` (check if you are importing the same type on model class and comparator class)

Comment: Is it possible you used different `Date`s (`java.util` vs `java.sql`) or that the Date objects are loaded by different classloaders?

Comment: I dont think so, I am only importing:

        import java.util.*;     
        import java.util.Date;
        import javax.swing.*;

Comment: you need post your "DateComparator.java:14" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're prof has provided a custom class called `Date` which is totally unrelated to `java.util.Date`. So you simply can't cast. If you really need to convert between those two different `Date` types, then you'll have to write the converters.

Best would be to remove the imports of `java.util.Date` from your code and use only the `Date` type that has been provided for this assignment.

Sorting those dates is possible the way you started. You'll have to reimplement your DateComparator to use the custom `Date` class instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: This was absolutely the case, thank you very much. After speaking to my Prof about what you the conflict between Date.java and java.util.Date the conclusion was that the project outline should have been more clear and to delete Date.java. You're advice has helped everyone in my class, thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear that :D Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you should check object type before cast object, using this code :

`if (d1 instanceof Date)
   Date d1 = (Date) a;`

Comment: this could be even worst in this case, if not instance of date: do nothing, leading to question as: why is doing nothing...

Comment: My apologies but I am unsure how to Incorporate you're code, I dont believe I could be importing java.sql because I am only importing java.util.*

The dates are made via the Professor's Date() SuperClass

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cast a date to an object.

I suspect you're probably importing java.sql.Date somewhere, and the conflict is actually between java.util.Date and java.sql.Date.

IMHO...

Comment: Thank you so much, after I looked at what you said and I just deleted the Date Class from the program and everything just worked! I'm sure I can find my way from here, You are amazing!